# "no test history available" error when running cal

Tags: benchmarking

```
vogar --benchmark --stream --verbose --mode jvm   ArraySortBenchmark.java
```

But it doesn't execute any benchmark, because "no test history available"

```
executing mkdir -p /tmp/vogar/573bd257-1b6e-4b91-92dd-1cdc6bdc491b
Actions: 1
skipped Users.louischiffre.projects.testing.ArraySortBenchmark.java
Task 0: prepare target
Task 1: rm /tmp/vogar/573bd257-1b6e-4b91-92dd-1cdc6bdc491b
  depends on completed task: prepare target
Task 2: rm /tmp/vogar/run
  depends on completed task: prepare target
running prepare target
executing rm -rf /tmp/vogar/run
executing mkdir -p /tmp/vogar/run
executing mkdir -p /tmp/vogar/run/tmp
executing mkdir -p /tmp/vogar/dalvik-cache
executing mkdir -p /tmp/vogar/run/user.home
running rm /tmp/vogar/run
running rm /tmp/vogar/573bd257-1b6e-4b91-92dd-1cdc6bdc491b
executing rm -rf /tmp/vogar/573bd257-1b6e-4b91-92dd-1cdc6bdc491b
executing rm -rf /tmp/vogar/run
parsing outcomes from 0 files
Skips summary:
  Users.louischiffre.projects.testing.ArraySortBenchmark.java (no test history available)
Outcomes: 1. Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 1. Took 129ms.
```

Interestingly, dn caliper example

> EnumSetContainsBenchmark.java

do not have this problem.